# The sign(x) function and its Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am trying to find the Fourier series of the $sign(x)$ function.

I know what the function means, but I did some research on it and I am stuck on finding the Fourier Series of it.

Comment: Since the sign function is not periodic, the Fourier series will depend on how you're periodizing it (i.e. on which interval you're looking at). Most natural would be the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. Or do you want to know its Fourier transform on the real line?

Comment: Yes I am looking at the interval you mentioned

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with the formulas for the coefficients?

Comment: Yes I know the formulas of the coefficients. I tried to find some examples regarding the sign(x) function but I could not find anything... Even the lecturer did not mention anything about this function.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you can show me how the Fourier series of the sign(x) looks like.

Comment: Can you write out the definition of what the Fourier series of a function $f$ is? It can be written in several different (but equivalent) ways, so to help you it would be nice to know which version you are using.